# Can someone translate this Chinese seal?

Tags: seal

Can some translate this seal please? The above is English “Norma” it was my Nana’s name she had the seal [image]made for her in Hong Kong many years ago. But I don’t know what the Chinese is under the name can some translate please?

Answer (score 1):

乐玛 /Lè mǎ/ is a transliteration of Norma. That means the actual meanings of the characters are irrelevant. However, transliteration sometimes forms words or phrases that are meaningful. For reference: 乐= happy; 玛= agate; carnelian

Notice the 瑪 on the seal is a traditional Chinese character. Not a simplified one 玛

Comment: Thank you for your response and So the Chinese is actually the name Norma? Cause I want to get it as a tattoo and I was hoping it would be her name in Chinese but I wasn’t sure

Comment: @Martinlillico 諾瑪(traditional) or 诺玛(simplified) would be better as a name. 諾 = promise